# Write value from 12 column on another worksheet if two conditions in columns 4 and 8 are true

Tags: excel, loops, if-statement, vba

```
Sub CreateTable() 
Dim bf As Boolean
Dim aTable(), aRes()
Dim i As Long, k As Long, n As Long
  With Worksheets("DOHADNÉ POLOŽKY")   ' List s tabulkou, kde se hleda
    i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    aTable = .Range("A1:P" & i).Value ' tabulka do pole

    ReDim aRes(1 To i + 1, 1 To 1) ' velikost pole
        End With



For i = 1 To UBound(aTable)  ' od 1 do poctu radky tabulky
    If aTable(i, 1) <> Empty Then ' kdyz neni prazdna
        If aTable(i, 4) = "Depo" And aTable(i, 8) = "CZK" Then


                    aTable(i, 12) = aRes(i, 1): i = i + 1
                                           End If
                                End If
Next i
' upload vysledku na list do sloupce J
Worksheets("List1").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(aRes), 1).Value = aRes
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "KUK"

End Sub
```

Something is wrong. It has no errors, but it doesn't write value in array I think. So the result on Worksheet("List1") is just empty.

Comment: I can see where `aTable` is picking the values up from but don't get how `aRes` is getting the values? Is it meant to pick them up from a `Range`?

Comment: it meant to be in this part   aTable(i, 12) = aRes(i, 1): i = i + 1, but i think it doesnt work proprerly

Comment: Shouldn't `aTable(i, 12) = aRes(i, 1)` be `aRes(i, 1) = aTable(i, 12)`?

Comment: As @Mrig said, I think you have your `aRes` assignment the wrong way around. It should be **`aRes(i,1) = aTable(i,12)`**. Also, you have this in a loop so you don't need `i = i + 1` (unless you specifically want to skip every other value from `aTable` array. In which case I would just use `Step 2`)

Comment: I've tried 'aRes(i,1) = aTable(i,12)' , but it still returns nothing.

Comment: Do you have data in `Column 12` satisfying both conditions?

Comment: Yes, i have for sure.

Comment: I tested this with @Mrig suggestion and got values copied to another worksheet